# I created a Javascript to-do list, but want to know how to keep the posts after browser refresh?

Tags: javascript

I wrote a JS to-do list, allowing the user to post an input on the page. However, I know that these posts disappear upon browser refresh. Could you possibly keep the posts in the page without being obliterated by the browser refresh by using Javascript cookies? And if so, how can I do that?

Please check full code here: [JSfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/mvL81epp/)

Here's the whole page code:

```js
<script>
 
(function(){
 
     var todo = document.querySelector( '#todolist' ),
      form = document.querySelector( 'form' ),
      field = document.querySelector( '#newitem' );
   field2 = document.querySelector( '#newitemTxt' );
   date = document.querySelector( '#datepicker' );

  form.addEventListener( 'submit', function( ev ) {
    var text = field.value;
 var text2 = field2.value;
 var textDate = date.value;
    if ( text !== '' && text2 !== '' && textDate !== '') {
      todo.innerHTML += '<li>' + '<span class="title">' + text + '</span>' + '<br />'  + text2 +  '<br />' + '<span class="date">' + textDate + '</span>' + '</li>';
 
    }
    ev.preventDefault();
  }, false);

  todo.addEventListener( 'click', function( ev ) {
    var t = ev.target;
    if ( t.tagName === 'LI' ) {
      t.parentNode.removeChild( t );
    };
    ev.preventDefault();
  }, false);

})();



</script>
```

```html
<form action="#">
   
      <div>
      <label class="desc" id="title" for="title">List Title</label>
        <input id="newitem" name="title" type="text" class="field text fn form-control" value="" size="8" tabindex="1">
      </div>
     
     
     <div>
      <label class="desc" id="title" for="title">Add Task Date</label>
        <input id="datepicker" name="title" type="text" class="field text fn form-control" value="" size="8" tabindex="1">
      </div>
     
     
     <div>
       <label class="desc" id="title4" for="Field4">
       Task Details
      </label>
       <textarea id="newitemTxt" name="Field4" class="form-control" spellcheck="true" rows="10" cols="50" tabindex="4"></textarea>
     </div>
   
       <div>
       <button   class="btn btn-info"  type="submit" value="Add"> POST </button>
       <button   class="btn btn-warning"  type="reset" value="Add"> RESET </button>
       </div>
    
     </form>
       
  </div> <!-- end of form-section-->
 

   <div class="col-md-8 result-section"> 
      <ul id="todolist"></ul>

   </div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[HTML5 storage](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/features/storage) should help you achieve this.

I created a quick [demo here](http://jsfiddle.net/mvL81epp/4/) using localstorage. You can read up on localsorage [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/localStorage)

```
//store string to a db called tasks
window.localStorage.setItem("tasks", "task 1");

//Read the previously saved string
var savedTasks = window.localStorage.getItem("tasks");
```

Comment: Yep, local storage seems like the way to go.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at html5 localstorage or sessionstorage they persist and store more data than cookies [sessionstorage](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/sessionStorage)

[Localstorage](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/localStorage)